# Get reference to component from CDK Overlay Portal

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I am using a service to instantiate Angular Material CDK Overlays using Component Portals.

Once I create a portal and attach it to an overlay, is there any way to access the component reference of the component that the portal creates? I want to be able to listen to events of that component from outside. For example:

```ts
const portal = new ComponentPortal(MyCoolComponent, /* ...etc */);
this.overlay.attach(portal);
// I'd like to be able to do something like...
// portal.MyCoolComponent.someEventEmitter.subscribe();
```

I've scoured the docs and the source, can't find a way to do it. I might have to resort to injecting a callback from the service into the component which is extremely messy.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Thу answer is here: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3593 :)

Comment: lol the answer is also down below, accepted about 6 months ago :D

Comment: I know, but this issue is much better :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `OverlayRef.attach` method returns a `ComponentRef`. A `ComponentRef` has a property `instance` which is an instance of your component. `ComponentRef` can be generic, so you know the type of the inner component.

See line 60 in [`OverlayRef` source code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-ref.ts)

```ts
attach<T>(portal: ComponentPortal<T>): ComponentRef<T>;
```

So you can do that in your code

```ts
const portal = new ComponentPortal(MyCoolComponent, ...etc);
const compRef: ComponentRef<MyCoolComponent> = this.overlay.attach(portal);

compRef.instance.someEventEmitter.subscribe();
```

Comment: I will check this out on monday. Thanks, probably was just a little brainfried :)

Comment: My god duh. Yes this was correct. Thanks. *eyeroll*